# Flexible width on d3.js graph?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

Please see http://jsbin.com/okUxAvE/28/

This has a width of 500px. The graph works as intended, with the nodes adjusting their position to stay in view as necessary.

How can I have this width be the arbitrary width of its **parent** instead of the specific 500px? For example, when viewing on a given device, the width might need to be 300px instead of 500px, but except for the change in width, everything should continue to work as in the example (i.e. no resizing of nodes).

Note that I don't care much about when the user resizes the window, although for orientation change it could be useful; so if anyone knows that it's a bonus, but not my main issue.

UPDATE, for clarification: I need 100% of the parent container, not 500px. I can't just use 100%. I know I could get the width of the parent, stick it into a variable and use that, but I'd like to know if there is a better way.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. The 500 width is determined by the number 500 in the source code, which you can change as you like?

Comment: To clarify, I'd like it to be flexible (read: a percentage), like 100%. In my actual use case, the SVG should be the width of the container, so basically I'd like 100% of that.

Comment: So something like `window.innerWidth`?

Comment: Yeah, I suppose. Not really a great question, looking back on it. Probably just need to get dimensions of the parent, and can also do that on window.resize. Thanks.